# How can I change the background color of ion-item when ion-toggle is enabled

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

How can I change the background color of ion-item when ion-toggle is enabled
Also showing Available when activating and showing Unavailable when closing

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>
        Status
        <span>Available</span>
        <span>Unavailable</span>
      </ion-label>
      <ion-toggle></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have to set a class on ion-item when your toggle is checked. Then, set --background: (color); inside the css class. EXAMPLE:

HTML:

```html
  <ion-item [class]="myToggle.checked?'checked':''">
    <ion-label>
      Status
      <span>Available</span>
      <span>Unavailable</span>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-toggle #myToggle></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

SCSS:

```css
ion-item.checked{
  --background: red;
}
```

Comment: agree with Miguel. You have to use component variables that ionic provides. Details can be found here https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables#component-variables

Answer (score 0):

Check the below Stack blitz and let me know if you need any modifications

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-toggle-eg-6apotx?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html,pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts
```